# Hide dropdown if no options found

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin for my dropdown. The dropdown is being populated by ajax using web services method. I want to hide dropdown if nothing has been found for the options.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
    <select id="drop_down"><select>
```

Jquery:

```
    var check_value = $("#drop_down").val();

    if(check_value==null){

    $("#drop_down").hide();

    }
```